# Conversion of one primitive type to another in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, overloading

In following piece of code

```
  class Main {

    void m1(double x){

        System.out.println("double");
    }

    void m1(float x){

        System.out.println("float");
    }

    void m1(long x){

        System.out.println("long");
    }

    void m1(byte x){

        System.out.println("byte");
    }

    void m1(short x){

        System.out.println("short");
    }

    void m1(int x){

        System.out.println("int");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Main m = new Main();
         m.m1(1);
    }
}
```

Why is the output "int" instead of "byte" or "long" or "short" or "float" or "double"?

If by following Automatic conversion from "byte" -> "short" -> "int" -> "long" -> "float" -> "double" then output should print "double" right?

(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/)

Comment: You invoke the int overload, by passing an int as a parameter. Why wouldn't it output int?

Comment: 1 = int. 1.0 = double. 1.0f = float. 1L = long; can't use a literal (without casting) for byte or short.

Comment: Ok. So basically to pass any other data type other than int (in this case), we should type cast and send. Is it correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Int literals (like `1`) are expressions of type `int`.

Overload resolution proceeds in a number of stages, looking for a method which can accept the parameters with the types you are passing.

1. If there is a single overload where the actual parameters have the same types as the formal parameters, invoke that.
2. If there is a single non-varargs overload where the actual parameters can be automatically converted (e.g. by widening or un/boxing) to be of the same types as the formal parameters, invoke that.
3. If there is a single varargs overload where the actual parameters can be automatically converted to be of the same types as the formal parameters invoke that.
4. Otherwise, error.

These phases are applied in turn, continuing until a match is found.

Since there is an overload of `m1` which takes `int`, a match is found in phase 1, so no conversion of that value to another type needs to happen.

Comment: Why doesn't the m1(long) gets called?

Comment: @Niharika because you are passing an int.

Comment: thanks got it :). so, to invoke m1(long/short/byte), is type casting the only way to do it?

Comment: @Niharika no, you can pass a variable of those types as the parameter. If you want to pass a literal, you can pass a long literal (`1L`); but for short and byte, yes, you have to cast.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, that primitive literal is of type int. Any numeric literal without a decimal point is of type *int*, unless you put a l/L in it: `1L` to turn it into a long. There is no 1 "byte" literal, you have to go `(byte) 1` to get there.

The compiler looks for the best fit, and uses that method that takes an int.

That is all there is to this. If you want to see other methods to be invojed, either cast the value to (long) for example, or start using values such as 1.0 instead of 1.

Regarding your comment: that *automatism* only kicks in when required. But in your case: A) you are using an *int* value B) there is an int-taking method. The compiler doesn't turn ints into longs into doubles for no reason!

Comment: 1 is best fit for short or byte also right? so, why m1(int) gets called? Can you be specific?

Comment: No: `1` is an int. It is not a byte or a short, or a long. This is the type it has, and the int overload is the one which will be invoked, because that's how overload resolution is defined to work.

Comment: @Niharika I made some updates, but seriously: you should consult some books/tutorials here. And: please dont forget to accept one of the answers at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic conversion only happens when a method accepts a wider type than the input.  For example, if you remove all the `void m1(..)` functions except the `long` version.  Then you can pass in an integer, and the integer will be automatically widened to a long.

In your example, there is a method that accepts an integer, so java will use that method instead, and there is no widening happening.

Comment: So why not m1(short) or m1(byte) gets called?